# DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data when trying to input data to database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

**when  input data to firestore database it's give this error called**

> Uncaught Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid
>   data. Unsupported field value: a custom HTMLTextAreaElement object
>   (found in field description)

```js
function errorsea(){
    var datafe=document.getElementById('bugsearch');
    firebase.firestore().collection("aboutproject").doc('10026275myprojectdescripton').set({description:datafe});

}
```

```html
  <form id="unknownerror">
        <textarea id="bugsearch"></textarea>
        <input type="button" onclick="errorsea()" name="senddata" value="senddata"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass an instance of an HTML element object to Firestore.  That's not valid.  You can only place plain objects or basic JavaScript vales like string, number, boolean, and null.

If you meant to pass the value of the text in the textarea element, you should probably pull it out of the element like this before passing it to Firestore:

```
var datafe=document.getElementById('bugsearch').value;
```

Comment: I would never expect this to work without `.value`.